# Should I kill peer methods when moving away from a UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, delegates

I have a situation that I have probably caused because of a lack of understanding of the general approach when using delegates. Can you help please?

Consider that I have a UIView, called 'homeViewController'.

This UIView instantiates a class called 'datastoreSync' which is a wrapper class that handles synchronising the backend with a remote server. I set the UIView as the delegate and assign the datastoreSync class to a variable inside the UIVIew

The class datastoreSync in turn fires off several classes and methods in sequence, setting itself as the delegate to each of these in turn. So... the datastoreSync class will instantiates 'assetTree' and sets itself as the delegate. It waits for the 'I'm all done!' delegate event, and then moves onto the next class.

The assetTree class (and all of the other little classes) are in turn delegates to NSURLConnection objects that handle the communications.

Now, the datastoreSync wrapper class can take some time to do it's job, and as it is running the user may move from my UIView to another UIView. When this happens the datastoreSync object stays alive for a little while as the assetTree class is doing it's job. When the assetTree class then sets itself as a delegate for the NSURLConnection and sets the NSURLConnection running the datastoreSync class falls out of scope. The assetTree class then cannot raise delegate events back to it and unfortunately the static variables inside the datastoreSync class that prevent it being run more than once consecutively cannot be reset, hence the datastoreSync class becomes 'locked' from being run again.

I am concerned that I am missing something fundamental. I need the datastoreSync class to remain alive if the user closes the device, so that they can start a synchronisation process and then lock their device, happy that the update will continue in the background but I do not know what i am supposed to do when moving from one UIView to another.

Do I send datastoreSync class a 'kill' command when moving away from the view and then code it to stop all of the delegate methods such as the assetTree class, in essence dropping it's NSURLConnection response?

I am unsure how to deal with this correctly. I am not scared of a lot of work, I just want it to be correct please.

Comment: When you say `UIView`, do you mean `UIViewController`?  They are very different things.

Comment: Yes I mean UIVIewController. Thank you for pointing out my error there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than sending a kill command when leaving a UIView, add logic at the beginning of a request to cancel/cleanup pending tasks from prior UIView that lock your `datastoreSync`. This allows the `datastoreSync` to stay alive during background processing and only cleans out tasks that would block new requests if necessary.

Comment: I am not sure that this would be good for maintenance as every page I may go to would have to know every process that the previous page has started on. I really do appreciate you giving me an answer though so please do not think that I am being ungrateful. Thank you.

Comment: You are correct : the UIView objects should have no knowledge of other views. To accomplish that, your datastoreSync class should only be concerned with syncing with your datastore.

Comment: I see what you are saying, this is approaching the problem from the other side and cancelling actions afterwards rather than before. This is closest to an answer on the subject so I am marking as answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> I am concerned that I am missing something fundamental.

Yup.

> **UIView**, called **'homeViewController**'.
>
> This **UIView** instantiates a **(controller class)**

You shouldn't do this; read up on M-V-C.

**Views** must only be concerned with *drawing* things; **Models** should only be concerned with *storing* things; the role of starting, stopping and in general *controlling* things belongs to **Controllers**.

So you should instantiate your database connection from app delegate (if you need it immediately on launch) or from one the view controllers (as a response to user actions) or from some other controller.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the reply. jim correctly pulled me up and pointed out that I meant UIViewController not UIView. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: While a database connection can be established in the AppDelegate we are concerned with the connection to the remote database here, via a webservice. The classes that we are discussing handle the synchronisation between the iOS database (code data) and the remote datbase (MS Sql server).